# KDE5 on arch: Option to swap CAPS and ESCAPE doesn't behave properly

Tags: arch-linux, kde, keyboard

I've tried using the KDE's keyboard settings (Input devices -> Advanced -> Caps Lock behavior -> Swap Esc and Caps Lock), and it swapped them. Escape behaves as a Caps lock, but Caps lock now acts as ESC *and* it also changes register at the same time.

I used Gnome previously and achieved this using dconf-editor with custom xdb options. On tiling managers, I did this through an auto-loaded config file. But the problem was that when you unplug your keyboard, the settings are reset, since the script is only run on startup. So I want KDE do manage this by itself, which it fails to do for some reason.

How to properly configure Caps and ESC to be swapped on KDE without the issues I described (and preferrably without a .Xprofile script, since I want my settings to apply every time a keyboard is plugged in)?

Comment: You can look into udev scripts. They can run at boot and hotplug.

Answer (score 0):

So I went with a temporary solution of just remapping CapsLock to Escape using "Make an additional Esc" option, since I don't really use the Caps Lock either way. This seems to work.